# Do the polyhedral homologies of a polyhedron coincide with the polyhedral homologies of its subdivision?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, convex-polytopes, simplicial-complexes, chain-complexes

Definition. A convex polytope is a compact finite intersection of hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Definition. The polycomplex is the following data set:

1. a set of convex polytopes, closed under transitions to a face
2. a set of affine isomorphisms between them, closed under composition and not containing non-trivial automorphisms ("we can affinely identify different polytopes, but we cannot glue a polytope with itself")

Comment. I prefer the definition: a polycomplex is a functor from a small thin groupoid to the category of convex polytopes, but the above will (probably) attract more people.

Comment.

1. Δ-complex is a special case of a polycomplex, when all polytope are simplices.
2. A polyhedron is a special case of a polycomplex, when each polytope "includes" no more than once in each polyhedron of higher dimension.
3. A simplicial complex is both a polyhedron and a Δ-complex.

Definition. $P_n$ is the set of all n-dimensional oriented polytopes of the polycomplex $P$ (for each n-dimensional polytope $P_n$ contains two elements: $X$ with one orientation and the other). Denote the natural involution on $P_n$ by $\neg$.

Definition. The polyhedral chain complex $P$ is the following chain complex:​

- $C_n(P) = FreeAb(P_n)/\sim$, where $\neg X \sim - X$ and $X \sim f(X)$ for each affine isomorphism $f$ from $P$ (an affine isomorphism transfers the orientation c $X$ on $f(X)$)
- $\partial \colon C_n(P) \to C_{n-1}(P)$ is defined on the basis as follows: $\partial X$ is the sum of its faces with induced orientations (for definiteness, the last frame vector enters the face, the rest set the orientation).

It is obvious from the orientation properties that $C(P)$ is a chain complex. The homology of $C(P)$ is called the polyhedral homology of $P$.

Comment. It is easy to see that the polyhedral homology of the Δ-complex coincides with its simplicial ones, since the resulting chain complexes are simply isomorphic.

I am interested in the following question: how to prove that the polyhedral homology of $P$ coincides with the polyhedral homology of any of its subdivisions $P'$? (i.e. $P'$ is a polycomplex obtained from $P$ only by a subdivision of the polytopes $P$ ). I'm sure it's true and probably very simple, but I can't think of a proof.

Comment: Did you try the method of acyclic models?

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon Thank you very much for reminding me of this theorem. Taking as models all (pairwise distinct) convex polytopes on the one hand and the standard $Δ^n$ simplices on the other, I can obtain two oppositely directed natural transformations between polyhedral and singular homology functors. I can prove that one of the compositions is equal to id by taking the standard simplices as models (the singular homology functor is both acyclic and free with respect to them).

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon To prove that another composition is equal to id, we need to find models with respect to which the polyhedral homology functor is acyclic and free. Obviously, for a functor to be free, it is necessary to take exactly all (pairwise distinct) convex polytopes. Now we need to somehow prove that the polyhedral homology of a polytope is trivial.

Comment: To do that, maybe you can find a chain homotopy contraction.  Perhaps something like choosing a basepoint for each polytope and then forming the cone with the basepoint as apex?

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon Is a chain contraction a homotopy equivalence on an acyclic subcomplex? Or is it a concept defined [here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/homology/sage/homology/chain_homotopy.html) ? Anyway, I don't understand your idea.

Comment: Yes, a chain contraction is a chain homotopy equivalance to zero.  (So we use an augmented version of the polyhedral complex with a copy of Z in degree -1)  Concretely, we need an operator f that raises degree by one, basically finding fillers for cycles.  Algebraically, you want df + fd = 1.  I'm suggesting that f could be a "cone" operation that takes a singular polytope and fills in a linear contraction to the basepoint.  This will be a singular polytope of dim one higher.  And if you apply f to a cycle, then you should get a filler for that cycle.  I'm happy to say more if needed

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon Thank you very much, but unfortunately I still don't understand. Let $P$ be a polytope, $C(P)$ its polyhedral chain complex. Do you propose to construct a homotopy equivalence $C(P) \to C(\mathrm{cone}(P))$? If yes, then I do not understand how to define a chain mapping in the opposite direction. Also, what do you mean by "singular polytope" in the context of polyhedral homologies?

Comment: I'm suggesting a degree +1 map f on C(P) that sends a basis vector (corresponding to A) to the basis vector corresponding to the cone on A.  Then I'm suggesting that df + fd = 1, and consequently, C(P) is chain homotopy equivalent to zero.

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon Let $P$ be a cube, let $A \in C_2(P)$ be the element corresponding to its face. $C_3(P)$ (which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$) has no element corresponding to a cone over $A$ in any sense. Maybe you are talking about singular homology, not simplicial/polyhedral?

Comment: Ah, I thought that a basis for $C_2(P)$ was all affine linear maps from all other polytopes.  So a basis is just given by the usual cells?  Then $C(P)$ should be isomorphic to the cw-chains on $P$?  I confess that I did not read the details of your construction.

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon Indeed.. I don't know why I didn't think of that, thanks.